# Send to Event Hub to a publisher using Qpid-Proton

Tags: python, qpid, azure-eventhub

From the following link, I found out that we can send data to publisher over AMQP protocol, https://github.com/ppatierno/azuresblite-examples. So, how to implement the same, i.e) Send to publisher(with & without token), using Qpid-proton python?

Answer (score -1):

send to a publisher means sending the message to a path like :

/Publishers/

You can use it as address for publishing message.

Paolo.

Comment: Thanks Paolo! Will the message get stored in Event Hub partitions and be viewed through some tool, like Service Bus Explorer?

Comment: Yes you can create listeners on event hub using Service Bus EXplorer and get all messages.

Comment: Okay, but I already sent the message to Event Hubs using Qpid-Proton to the uri:
python send.py -a amqps://<keyname>:<key>@<namespace>.servicebus.windows.net/<eventhubname>/Publishers/<device_name>. The message is sent, but in Service bus Explorer (created a consumer group listener for $Default, no other is using that group) I get nothing. Because of this result, I asked the question in previous comment.

Comment: Are you sure that the message is sent ? I never used the python client but the C client.